# How can you disable a.NET ImageButton control on the client side when the ImageButton has an onClick event handler?

Tags: c#, postback, imagebutton

The purpose here is to prevent users from clicking the button multiple times during the submit/click. I've tried the different solutions for a Button control but they do not apply to an ImageButton.

Comment: So... what _have_ you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
imgbutton.OnClientClick = "this.disabled = true;";
```

This will disable the button at the client side as soon as it is pressed. (The syntax may be off - I can't test this code right now.)